# calc 2 integration wrt y problem

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm kind of surprised that I am having a hard time with this problem. It is possible that I am not looking at it in the right way:

"Sketch the region enclosed by the given curves. Decide whether to integrate with respect to x or y. Then find the area of the region.
$$
\begin{cases}
2y=5\ \sqrt{x} \\
 2y+4x=9 \\
 y=3  \\
\end{cases}
$$

I sketched it, solved both equations for x and then integrated two intervals, on $[0, \frac 52]$ and the other $[\frac 52, 3]$

The result I got is $3.398333333 $ and that is the same as what wolframalpha got, which is to say that my calculations are correct.

But it is not the correct answer to the webwork question.

I rewrote my work on the problem so that it is readable to humans other than myself here https://i.stack.imgur.com/nENl2.jpg

What am I not seeing here? Any ideas? TIA

Comment: Webwork is finicky. You probably need to put it in  fractional form. Also sometimes webwork is just wrong

Comment: I have one more try as they only allow three, and I'd prefer to have perfect marks for the webwork component.

Do you think this is worth bugging the prof about? I hate to do that, and it is generally more likely that I (or any student) screwed up somewhere.

Comment: Wait 5 min I’m going to solve it real quickly to check your work

Comment: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/area-between-curves-calculator/area%20y%3D3%2C%20y%3D%5Cfrac%7B5%7D%7B2%7Dsqrt%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%2C%20y%3D%5Cfrac%7B9%7D%7B2%7D-%5Cfrac%7B4x%7D%7B2%7D   I tried doing it by hand but I messed up the algebra somewhere! See the link for the solution

Comment: Ah, I guess it wants that little area between all 3 curves.  That does make sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The region enclosed by the three curves has corners at $(1,5/2)$, $(36/25,3)$, and $(3/4,3)$.  It is unclear what purpose integrating a region with $x$ or $y$ values in $[0,5/2]$ has.  The area of a triangle with these vertices is
$$  \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{36}{25} - \frac{3}{4} \right) \frac{1}{2} = \frac{69}{400}  \text{,}  $$
so your decimal approximation of the correct value is very far from correct.  (This is not the value of the integral, it is a coarse estimate to judge the scale of the correct answer.  In fact, it differs from the correct answer by $\frac{1}{300}$.)

Comment: JacFrall has it up in the comments. It's the same number as I got for the second interval. I was thinking of the y=3 as an upper bound and 0 as the lower bound, but it seems like I should have thought of it as one of the boundaries of the area in question.